# How to pass data from an observed class to another?

Tags: ios, swift, class, swiftui, observable

This post is related to [this post that I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830709/how-to-pass-observed-properties-to-other-classes). While there is no initialization error anymore now,  it seems that there's one problem here: when you change the username in the textfield, the url and payment detail will not get updated still? Any idea how to solve this?

```
struct passingData: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userData: UserData
    @ObservedObject var images: ImageURL
    @ObservedObject var payment: Payment
    
    init() {
       let data = UserData()
      
       self.userData = data
       self.images = ImageURL(userData: data)
       self.payment = Payment(userData: data)
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            TextField("Enter userName", text: $userData.userName)
            Text("url is \(images.imageURL)")
            Text("Payment detail: \(payment.paymentDate)")
        }
    }
}


class Payment: ObservableObject{
    @Published var paymentDate = ""
    @ObservedObject var userData: UserData
    init(userData: UserData){
        self.userData = userData
        loadPaymentDate()
    }
    
    func loadPaymentDate(){
        self.paymentDate = "last payment date from \(userData.userName) is 12.12.22 "
    }

}


class ImageURL: ObservableObject{
    @Published var imageURL = ""
    @ObservedObject var userData: UserData
    init(userData: UserData){
        self.userData = userData
        loadImageURL()
    }
    
    func loadImageURL(){
        self.imageURL = "123_\(userData.userName).com"
    }
}



class UserData: ObservableObject{
    @Published var userName = ""
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean the payment detail isn't updated?  Are you referring to the value of the `paymentDate` property?  You only set that value when you create the `Payment` object. It won't change just because the `userData.userName` property has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `@ObservedObject` property wrapper in class, it is designed for `View` only.

Here is a demo of solution for one class. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
import Combine

class ImageURL: ObservableObject{
    @Published var imageURL = ""

    private var userData: UserData            // << reference type
    private var observer: AnyCancellable?
    init(userData: UserData){
        self.userData = userData

        // observe changes of userName via publisher explicitly
        self.observer = userData.$userName.sink(receiveValue: {[weak self] _ in
            self?.loadImageURL()
        })

        loadImageURL()
    }

    func loadImageURL(){
        self.imageURL = "123_\(userData.userName).com"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to swift and I don't know much about AnyCancellable protocol. This works! Thanks!