# SwiftUI Start func in Model after another model finished func

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

How can I start a function in a Model that depends by another Model?

On the view I can use .`onReceive`.

Can I use something that doesn't depends by the view but only by the model?
I wrote a simple code to reproduce the behavior

```
class Model1: ObservableObject {

    @Published var userName: String?
    @Published var userFavoriteFilms: [String] = []
    @Published var userLoaded: Bool = false
    
    init() {
        fetchUser()
    }
    func fetchUser() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.userName = "foo"
            self.userFavoriteFilms = ["Film2"]
            self.userLoaded = true
        }
    }
}

class Model2: ObservableObject {
    
    struct Film: Identifiable, Hashable {
        var name:String
        var isFavorite:Bool
        var id:String {
            name
        }
    }
    @Published var films: [Film] = []
        
    var model1: Model1
    
    init(model1: Model1) {
        self.model1 = model1
        /// I would like to add here something like .onReceive(model1.$userLoaded) --> fetchFilms()
    }
    
    func fetchFilms() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            let filmsFetch = ["Film1","Film2","Film3"]
            for f in filmsFetch {
                var isFavorite = false
                if self.model1.userFavoriteFilms.firstIndex(of: f) != nil {
                    isFavorite = true
                }
                let film = Film(name:f, isFavorite:isFavorite)
                self.films.append(film)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var model1: Model1 = Model1()
    
    var body: some View {
        MyView()
            .environmentObject(Model2(model1: model1))
    }
}
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model2: Model2
    var body: some View {
        let userName = model2.model1.userName
        VStack {
            if userName != nil {
                Text("Hi \(userName!)")
            }
            else {
                Text("User loading...")
            }
            List {
                ForEach(model2.films
                ) { film in
                    HStack {
                        Text(film.name)
                        Text("\(film.isFavorite ? "favorite":"")")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(model2.model1.$userLoaded) { bool in
            if bool {
                model2.fetchFilms()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846183/how-to-pass-data-from-an-observed-class-to-another#) should help you.

Comment: look into `.sink` with `Combine`

Comment: thanks, I solved with sink and combine

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI you normally wouldn't do this. Instead:

"You can model your data using value type and manage its life cycle and side effects with a reference type."
[WWDC 2020 Data Essentials in SwiftUI 11:55](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/?time=715)

This means model your data with value types, i.e. structs, and manage their lifecycle with a reference type, i.e. an `ObservableObject`, normally named a "Loader" or a "Fetcher". In the View you manage the loader's life cycle using `@StateObject` which will create the Loader just before the View appears and destroy it when the View disappears (Note: with some container Views like TabView this is not always the case).

That means do something like this:

```
struct UserModel {
   var name: String?
   var favoriteFilms: [String] = []
   var loaded: Bool = false
}

class UserLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: UserModel?

    init() {
        UserService.shared.fetchUser()
        .map {
            // convert what the service returns into your user model struct.
        }
        .assign(to: &$user) // assign is how we properly complete a Combine pipeline in an ObservableObject. The pipeline is automatically tied to the lifecycle of this object.
    }
}
```

Because usually the model data is loaded asynchronously, your Views need to be designed to show something when the user hasn't been loaded yet. This can be as simple as: `Text(loader.user?.name ?? "")`. Another trick is to make the loader store an array of users and initialise it with an empty array, then you don't need to worry about optional handling; this works great in a `List`.